# checking if inside script finishes execution before continuing in linux

Tags: java, linux, bash

I have a script called A.sh, it does some tasks and has another script inside of itself called B.sh The second script launches a java file and does some processing. In the java file, there's a thread inside which makes the script run concurrently. the main script A.sh depends on the outcome of b.sh to do file management and cleanup but because of the thread, its executing concurrently. Is there a in linux that can check if the inner script is done before continuing with the other tasks?